# Learning Mathematics: unique knowledge of math.

Tags: self-learning, philosophy, learning

I've come to a point where I now more fully (like 99%) understand that math is about specialized/unique knowledge which can't be summarized by some grand scheme or united principle.

So my question is, despite occasional uniting understandings of mathematical knowledge, after decades of studying math, does this cornerstone of specialized knowledge change into a more united conceptual understanding?

This question is for those who have studied math after high school for more than 20 years.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes and no. One has more conceptual understanding with more experience. On the other hand it is like with new literature. There is always a new story, even if we have a conceptual understanding of some literature.

Comment: No concept of unification like the Grall quest for physicists about unification of great theories. After some 50+ years specializing in Maths, for example, on such a site, I feel like an old physician who has seen many diseases, able to diagnose and treat  properly a certain number of them, and/or leave to specialized colleagues patient's diseases that I am unable to diagnose...